# Writing a function to find the factorial of an inputed number

Tags: python, for-loop, factorial

I have written a code to calculate the factorial of any number a user inputs. The code is not running. I want to know what have I done wrong in this code.

```
num = int(input("Please enter a number : "))
fact = num
lst = list(range(1, num + 1))
lst.sort(reverse = True)
print(lst)
for x in lst : 
    while x > 1:
        fact = fact * (x - 1)
print(fact)
```

Comment: `while x > 1:` This is an infinite loop because you do not change the value of `x` inside the `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is because or your `while x>1`. Basically, your programme loops for a fixed value of x, which won't change.
You're pretty close:

```
num = int(input("Please enter a number : "))
fact = num
lst = list(range(1, num + 1))
lst.sort(reverse = True)
print(lst)
for x in lst : 
    if x > 1:
        fact = fact * (x - 1)
    else:
       break
print(fact)
```

Comment: The code that you have edited has worked perfectly fine. But I still do not get it. where was I wrong? Was my while loop wrong?

Comment: You have 2 loops: the for and the while loop. The for loops increments x when you reach the end of the block. However, you have the while loop that does `fact = fact * (x - 1)` until x reaches 1. This will never happen because x gets decreased only at the end of the `for` block (which includes the while block)

Comment: great! Now I get it